# Ampersand in site names should not be escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, character-escaping

Noticed this while glancing at the Anime and Manga, but the ampersands are... inconsistent.  One uses the HTML entity; the other is more sane.

[image: same exact image, but with a circle!]

This should get resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report, we'll get a fix out for this soon.

Comment: Just make the ampersand shift everything forward to the next tabular row like it does in TeX, and everything will be fine.

Comment: @Emrakul **+1** for TeX reference. Best typesetting system ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This should get resolved.

Indeed it should. And it is in version 0.1.4.